# saving individual plots from a faceted plot output

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have generated 8 plots of yearly data with the following code

```
pl <- dlply(BC_yr, .(STATION_NAME), function(dat) {
  ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = year, y = CLDD_yr, group = STATION_NAME)) + geom_line() + 
    geom_point() + xlab("Year") + ylab("Yearly CLDD") +
    ggtitle(dat$STATION_NAME[1]) +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm")
})

pl
```

I am now interested in saving individual plots withe the correct title.

I am approaching this with a for-loop like so

```
for(p in pl){
  ggsave(dat$STATION_NAME[1]+"plot.pdf" height = 4, width = 11, units = "in")
}
```

I know i need to format my output file as something like `str(p.STATION_NAME)+"plot.pdf"`

But I can not get the appropriate formatting passed to the function such that the output is successful.

How does one do this in r?

Comment: `+` doesn't concatenate strings in R. You need to use `paste()` or `paste0()`.

Comment: gotcha. thank you ... unfortunately I am having an issue referencing `dat` now.. but this was helpful anyway.

Comment: `ggsave()` saves only the last plot by default and the help page does not offer a mechanism for retrieving earlier plots. So I think you need to put the save operation in that `dlply` call.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're iterating over all values of `pl`, you can try this:

```
for(p in pl){
  ggsave(paste(dat$STATION_NAME[p],"plot.pdf",sep="-") height = 4, width = 11, units = "in")
}
```

Comment: I am getting this `Error in paste(dat$STATION_NAME[p], "plot.pdf", sep = "-") : 
  object 'dat' not found`

Comment: In my answer, i'm assuming `dat` is the `data.frame` with the different *station names*. If it's not, you may need to subset from the original data.frame (i assume it's `BC_yr`, but it's unclear in your example).

Comment: I see. I will give this a try... it seems to make sense though... dat here is what I am passing to my function in ddply

Comment: `Error in BC_yr$STATION_NAME[p] : invalid subscript type 'list'`  is what i get whith this action